# Highlighting both image and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

In the following example, I need to show, when on-mouse either on the image or the text, the image and the text gets hovered. I have done the development on the first product, but I need this to work on the others as well. How do I achieve this?

The hovering should be separate without giving separate ids for each element.

Here is the example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.0-packed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helper-plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helper-plugins/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helper-plugins/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="helper-plugins/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(function() {

                //  Basic carousel, no options
                $('#foo0').carouFredSel();

                //  Basic carousel + timer, using CSS-transitions
                $('#foo1').carouFredSel({
                    auto: {
                        pauseOnHover: 'resume',
                        progress: '#timer1'
                    }
                }, {
                    transition: true
                });

                //  Scrolled by user interaction
                $('#foo2').carouFredSel({
                    auto: false,
                    prev: '#prev2',
                    next: '#next2',
                    pagination: "#pager2",
                    mousewheel: true,
                    swipe: {
                        onMouse: true,
                        onTouch: true
                    }
                });

                //  Variable number of visible items with variable sizes
                $('#foo3').carouFredSel({
                    width: 360,
                    height: 'auto',
                    prev: '#prev3',
                    next: '#next3',
                    auto: false
                });

                //  Responsive layout, resizing the items
                $('#foo4').carouFredSel({
                    responsive: true,
                    width: '100%',
                    scroll: 2,
                    items: {
                        width: 400,
                    //  height: '30%',  //  optionally resize item-height
                        visible: {
                            min: 2,
                            max: 6
                        }
                    }
                });

                //  Fuild layout, centering the items
                $('#foo5').carouFredSel({
                    width: '100%',
                    scroll: 2
                });

            });
        </script>
<script language="javascript">
function hightlight() 
{

    document.getElementById("textspan").style.color = "blue";
    document.getElementById("ul").style.border = "1.5px solid black";
    //document.getElementById("textspan").setStyle("color","blue");
    //document.getElementById("ul").setStyle("border","1px solid blue");
}
function removehightlight() 
{
    document.getElementById("textspan").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("ul").style.border = "1px solid #999";
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style3 {color: #000000}
-->
</style>
</head>
    <body>

                <table id="Main" >
  <tr>
<td class="tb 1 clearfix"><a id="prev2" class="button" href="a.css"></a></td>

<td id="tb2" class="list_carousel">
                <div id="foo2">
                    <table id="product"><tr><td id="picbox"><div id="ul" onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"> <img src="Images/Laptop.JPG" alt="picture"></div></td></tr><tr><td onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"><a class="style1" href="http://etrege.com/ebay_new/index.php"><span class="style3" id="textspan" >This is a product</span></a></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr></table>
<table id="product"><tr><td id="picbox"><div id="ul" onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"> <img src="Images/Handbags1.jpg" alt="picture"></div></td></tr><tr><td onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"><a class="style1" href="http://etrege.com/ebay_new/index.php"><span class="style3" id="textspan" >This is a product</span></a></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr></table>
<table id="product"><tr><td id="picbox"><div id="ul" onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"> <img src="Images/Wafflemaker.jpg" alt="picture"></div></td></tr><tr><td onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"><a class="style1" href="http://etrege.com/ebay_new/index.php"><span class="style3" id="textspan" >This is a product</span></a></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr></table>
<table id="product"><tr><td id="picbox"><div id="ul" onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"> <img src="Images/camera.jpg" alt="picture"></div></td></tr><tr><td onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"><a class="style1" href="http://etrege.com/ebay_new/index.php"><span class="style3" id="textspan" >This is a product</span></a></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr></table>
<table id="product"><tr><td id="picbox"><div id="ul" onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"> <img src="Images/Laptop.JPG" alt="picture"></div></td></tr><tr><td onmouseover="hightlight()" onmouseout="removehightlight()"><a class="style1" href="http://etrege.com/ebay_new/index.php"><span class="style3" id="textspan" >This is a product</span></a></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr></table>
                </div></td>
<td id="tb3" class="clearfix"><a id="next2" class="button" href="a.css"></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not a valid markup. `Same ids for multiple elems`

Answer (score 0):

Just a word of advice... 
try putting the image inside the hyperlink `a` tag. Then you can set some CSS class name to the link, '`class="imageLink"` for example.

After that, if you write a hover effect for both the link and the image, inside that class, you can filter out the image in that class. Here's the example...

```
.imageLink a:hover
{
   ... link hover effect ...
}
.imageLink img:hover
{
   ... image hover effect ....
}
```

I'm not entirely sure about this. But, I have achieved similar effect with this technique in other places.